# PHP - Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, xml

I want to try in PHP with XML an result and price.
Only I get the following error.

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\help27.php on line 7

```
<?php
$XML = simpleXML_load_file('newtitel.XML');
echo "<strong>update price from a book</strong><br />";
$result=$XML->xpath(
'//book[isbn="2345377445567"]');
$result[0]->price = 70;
$XML->asXML('newtitel.XML');
?>
```

What did I wrong? Thanks in advance.
Sorry, I didn't know that, that is possible, I will do that my friend!

Comment: It will be helpful to get answer, if you can paste in question text also content of `newtitel.XML` file

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the first `<price>` node - with the index `[0]` - too:

```
$result[0]->price[0] = 70;
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/htn7hz